# Checkbox selected when textbox is in focus in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, textbox

I am having a gridview with a checkbox and two textboxes. what I am trying to do is to check the checkbox automatically as soon as the focus is on the textboxes in the grid view. Can anyone help me with this please?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dglist" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EditRowStyle-    
Wrap="true" Font-Size="9px" Width="500px" 
EmptyDataText="Empty" OnRowDataBound="dglist_RowDataBound"
OnRowCommand="dglist_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="dglist_RowEditing">
<HeaderStyle Width="1%" CssClass="Gridheader" />
<RowStyle ForeColor="Black" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSelect" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField> 
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TextBox1">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Texbox runat="server" ID="txtBox1" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TextBox2">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Texbox runat="server" ID="txtBox2" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks,
Su

Comment: You can't do this in code behind.  You'll need JavaScript/jQuery.  If (when) you have difficulty, post the rendered HTML (not the asp.net markup) along with the JavaScript/Jquery.  If you include a jsFiddle, more people will respond and quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript

```
function check()
{
    var chk=document.getElementId("chkSelect");
    chk.checked=true;
}
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TextBox1" onFocus="check();"><ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:gridview ID="grdCustomer" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <itemtemplate>
                <asp:checkbox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />Check
            </itemtemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:templatefield>
            <itemtemplate>
                <asp:textbox ID="txtData" runat="server" onfocus="Check(this);">
                </asp:textbox>
            </itemtemplate>
        </asp:templatefield>
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Check(lnk) {
        var dataGrid = document.all['grdCustomer'];
        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
        var checkBox = dataGrid.rows[row.rowIndex].cells[0].childNodes[0];
        checkBox.checked = true;
    }
</script>
```